# Is there a PHP equivalent to Oracle Reports?

Tags: php, oraclereports

I'm quite used to work with Oracle Reports to build PDF reports and I'm looking for an equivalent tool/library for PHP.

Oracle Reports allows to rapidly position fields on a page, make tables based on loops, display headers on each page, insert graphics...
It's mainly based on a SQL query, but for what I'm looking for, I just like to have the simplicity of the features described before (and maybe more like charts).

I've used JasperReports in Java but I think it's not the right tool for this job, any suggestion (a free tool would be better) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's anything like Oracle Reports, but for building PDF reports, I'd recommend [LiveDocx](http://www.livedocx.com/).

Comment: Although this shouldn't matter that much (considering Oracle is mentioned), LiveDocx is a commercial product for the most part (with a free version).

Comment: I forget to give the precision, question updated, thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at it.